# Finding difficult to commit to my repo using sandbox

Tags: git

I'm using Sandbox, cloned from GitHub using the git clone command, trying to commit a file, using git commit -m "My first commit" and getting this error: "src refspec refs/heads/master does not match any" [git fatal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2Vzl.png) the file has been staged but won't commit in my local repo
I have tried git pull --rebase origin [branch] but still getting the same error, Based on my research have been able to understand that my local repo has not yet been updated with any changes made in the remote repo, tried listing out my branches locally and remotely using git branch -a and git branch -r command on sandbox but I got nothing [branch result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93AxC.png)
Can anyone help me out on this I'm stuck.

Comment: You should have configured your Git username and then run `git commit`. You tried all the correct steps, but in the wrong order.

Comment: Also you didn't spell the commands to configure your username correctly. Pay attention to the message that tells you how to configure your username.

Comment: I already fixed the username spelling issues @mkrieger1, I will re-configure and run git commit again